# Search a facebook users videos via graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is is possible to get a list or search a Facebook users videos for text within a description?

Note: This user has granted users_videos permissions in my app.

I have been able to upload a video, but there is no way to associate the videos with an album so i'm having a hard time finding a way to associate the video to a certain item in my app and the best way I can think of is by associating the video with an id in the description field.

I'm guessing this must be done thru the FQL. If so, does anyone have examples snippets for searching the videos? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't search video by their description or title directly from facebook. This is because facebook doesn't allow non-indexable columns in WHERE clause.

One workaround (but a bad one) what I could think of, is to fetch all the videos and search them locally. This is bad because fetching all the videos might be dead-slow and thus losing the usability in your application.

But for your case, why don't you associate video ID to the items in your own database?
If you upload a video, facebook returns the ID that video got, so you can associate this id with the item you need in your own database, so you'll always know, which video goes by which item.

Later on you can call those videos out from facebook by their ID using either Graph API or FQL